# I am trying to connect Logitech K380 Keyboard to my Chrome laptop

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, chromebook

It says Authentication failed while connecting to "K830". I have tried to put it in Bluetooth mode and it still doesn't work.

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you detail the steps you are taking? What model of Chromebook do you have? Also what version of ChromeOS is it?

Answer (score 0):

I expect the first method you tried was plugging the receiver dongle into your Chromebook's USB port.  If you have other wireless Logitech products nearby, try unplugging those dongles first since they can interfere with each other.